# How to keep db password in application server secure?

Tags: spring, spring-security

In an enterprise java project that uses spring security, what are the ways to keep some private keys secure at the application server such as weblogic?

Comment: Usually we keep database username and password in a properties file ....

Answer (score 1):

If you store the credentials in a property file.
You could change the permission on the configuration files after they have been deployed.
For example you can give readonly access to the application server user, such that nobody else can read the credentials.